# Ping list of computers FAST with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ping

I've pinged a list of computers many times however I am trying to use Python for my first time with a list of about 4,000 computer names and my script is very slow.  How would I go about making this much faster and writing the output to a comma delimited text file?

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import datetime

#Get current date and time
now = datetime.datetime.now()
dt = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
dtnow = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

#Open the file and read into memory
fh = pd.read_csv('list.csv')

#Fix column headers by replacing the spaces with a underscore
fh.columns = fh.columns.str.strip().str.replace(' ', '_')

#Read the computer names into a variable called "computers"
computers = fh.Machine_Name
#Debug - Uncomment line below to see a list of computer names from csv file
#print(computers)

def ping(comp):
    args = ["ping", "-n", "2", comp]
    p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, error = p.communicate()
    if 'bytes=32' in output:
        writetofile(comp, ',online')
    else:
        writetofile(comp, ',offline')
    #endIf
#endDef

def writetofile(compname, data):
    with open('DLPProv_' + dt + '.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(compname + data + '\n')
    #endWith
#endDef

for i in computers:
    ping(i)
#endFor

f.write('END: ' + dtnow)
f.close()
```

I've tried using the code that @rolandsmith posted but i'm getting errors:

```
import concurrent.futures as cf
import os
import pandas as pd
from pythonping import ping

#Open the file and read into memory
fh = pd.read_csv('list.csv')

#Fix column headers by replacing the spaces with a underscore
fh.columns = fh.columns.str.strip().str.replace(' ', '_')

#Read the computer names into a variable called "computers"
computers = fh.Machine_Name

def pingworker(address):
    rv = ping(address, count=4)
    if rv.success():
        return address, True
    return address,False

with cf.ThreadPoolExecutor() as tp:
    res = tp.map(pingworker, computers)
```

Comment: I think the `ping` function takes more time. Could add a debug statement before and after it printing to calculate the time it takes?

Comment: Use `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`'s `map` or `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool`'s `imap`/`imap_unordered` to get thread-based parallelism? That's the usual solution for latency bound problems like this.

Answer (score 1):

When you think a script is slow, you should *measure* what causes it to be slow. Use e.g. [line-profiler](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler).

My *guess* would be that in this case it is the subprocess that takes up most of the time. Ideally, you want to remove the overhead of starting a process for each ping. So instead of calling the `ping` program, install the [pythonping](https://pypi.org/project/pythonping/) module. This allows you to perform an ICMP echo request from Python. Note that this uses raw sockets, so depending on the OS you might need to run the script as root or make it capable of using raw sockets.
Using this module removes the overhead of using subprocess.

Next, when your script is doing this, it is mostly waiting for a reply from the network. So we use a `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` to start more than one ping in parallel

```
import concurrent.futures as cf
import os
from pythonping import ping

def pingworker(address):
    rv = ping(address)
    if rv.success():
        return address, True
    return address,False

with cf.ThreadPoolExecutor() as tp:
    res = tp.map(pingworker, list_of_addresses)
```

After this, `res` is a list of 2-tuples, each containing the address and boolean if it failed or succeeded.

Note that from Python 3.5 onward, a `ThreadPoolExecutor` launches 5*N threads, where N is the number of cores on your machine. So for a four-core machine, there would be 20 ping calls running at once. You can experiment with the `max_workers` parameter when creating a `ThreadPoolExecutor`, but at a certain point you're going to saturate your network connection with ping calls.

**Edit**

The `pythonping.ping` function requires an *IP address*, not a name. So you would have to do name lookup first. Luckily, this is built into the `socket` module. You can use e.g. [`socket.gethostbyname_ex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.gethostbyname_ex) to do IPv4 address lookup. Or [`socket.getaddrinfo`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.getaddrinfo) to get both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.

If you have a list of names, presuming you're using IPv4, you could change the worker like this:

```
import concurrent.futures as cf
import socket
import os
from pythonping import ping

def pingworker(name):
    """
    Ping a hostname.

    Arguments:
        name (str): hostname:

    Returns:
        a 3-tuple (hostname, IP-address, ping-result)
        where hostname and IP-address are strings and
        ping-result is a bool.
    """
    try:
        _, _, IPs = socket.gethostbyname_ex(name)
        address = IPs[0]
    except socket.gaierror:
        return name, None, False  # Name lookup failed.
    rv = ping(address)
    if rv.success():
        return name, address, True
    return name, address, False   # Host doesn't respond.

with cf.ThreadPoolExecutor() as tp:
    res = tp.map(pingworker, list_of_names)
```

I also modified the worker function to also return the IP address. That way you can distinguish a host that doesn't return pings from a host whose name cannot be resolved.

Comment: Requires raw sockets? That's... suboptimal. Third party packages that require admin/root to run are giant security holes; if the owner's creds get compromised (or the owner decides to be malicious themselves), the package can silently be updated to hijack machines. Clearly `ping` itself runs without admin/root, so I'm somewhat skeptical of the need for it in the package.

Comment: It doesn't actually require root privileges, just the cap_net_raw capability that can be set on the file by root. This is what ping does on my box.

Comment: @ShadowRanger If this was a *server* application, I would agree. Since it is not, the danger is much less. Second, your `ping` binary *also* runs `setuid` root.

Comment: @randomusername I suspect that cap_net_raw is linux specific. And the OP doesn't mention which OS he is using.

Comment: @RolandSmith  Thanks for the detailed response.  I'm not sure If I'm adding the computer names correct because I'm getting a lot of errors when running your script.

Comment: @antmar904 The `ping` function requires an *IP address*, not a name. See its documentation.